# django character set with MySQL weirdness

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mysql-error-1267

I'm seeing

```
OperationalError (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")
```

It looks like some of my variables are UTF8 strings

'name': 'p\xc7\x9d\xca\x87\xc9\x9f\xc4\xb1\xc9\xa5s Badge'

Is this a configuration issue? If so, how can i solve it? I'd like to handle everything in Unicode (I think).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears your database is defaulted to latin1_swedish_ci, and therefore cannot accept all utf8 characters.  You need to change the configuration of the MySQL database tables to use utf8_general_ci.  A good blogpost about this (with links to a tool) can be found at [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/17/converting-character-sets/)

Answer (score 47):

You can change the table encoding via the shell:

```
$ manage.py shell
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
>>> results=[]
>>> for row in cursor.fetchall(): results.append(row)
>>> for row in results: cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE %s CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE     utf8_general_ci;' % (row[0]))
```

https://mayan.readthedocs.org/en/v0.13/faq/index.html

Comment: This worked great! But have in mind that your database charset will remain as it was, to change it also execute: `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Comment: You may also need to update each table's *columns* too, not just the database and its tables.

Comment: This works great! On caveat: the extra spaces in the last line somehow messed up the command. Removing them for proper execution.

Answer (score 1):

You will add OPTIONS in django settings file like below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
        'NAME': 'sarpanchDb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'tiger',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Also you will need to do change in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then restart mysql service

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Cross check it worked or not using following query

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR 
Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

You should get following output

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I was missing the mysql configurations file thank you