# Django ajax unicode error

Tags: mysql, django, unicode

Hi I have a small javascript function which dynamically filters my form:

```
// set up a new XMLHttpRequest variable
var request = false;
try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (trymicrosoft) {
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (othermicrosoft) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (failed) {
            request = false;
        }
    }
}

// if no request then throw up an alert window
if (!request)
    alert("Error initializing XMLHttpRequest!");

// this function takes the island group value and sends it to the url as a get variable
function getIslandName(lang) {
    var islandGroup = document.getElementById("id_island_group").value;

    if (islandGroup == '') {
        // if Not Specified re-selected then set data to null and bypass updatePage()
        var data = null; 
        update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
    } 
    else {
        var url = "../collections/find_island?island_group=" + escape(islandGroup);
        // alert("Ready state is: " + request.readyState);
        // alert("url: " + url);
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
        request.send(null);
    }    
} 

// what to do when http ready state changes
function updatePage() { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {

            // get response array
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText); 
            update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
        }  
        // some error checking
        else if (request.status == 404) {
            alert("Request url does not exist");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error: status code is " + request.status);
        }
    }
}   

function update_select(select, data) {
    // find and remove existing options
    select.find('option').remove();

    var optionText = document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML

    select.append($('<option value>' + optionText + '</option>'));
    // loop through results and append to select as options
    for (var k in data) {
        select.append($('<option value="'+data[k]+'">'+data[k]+'</option>'));
    }
}
```

And my forms:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    island_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=False,
        label=ugettext_lazy('Island Group'), 
        initial=None,
        queryset=Localityonline.objects.values_list('islandgroup', flat=True).distinct('islandgroup').exclude(islandgroup=None).order_by('islandgroup'), 
        empty_label=ugettext_lazy("Not Specified"), 
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":'searchfield', "onChange":'getIslandName()'})
    )
    island_name = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        label=ugettext_lazy('Island Name'), 
        initial=None,
        choices=DEFAULT_CHOICES,
        #queryset = Localitymayor.objects.values_list('islandname', flat=True).distinct('islandname').exclude(islandname="n/a").order_by('islandname'), 
        #empty_label=ugettext_lazy("Not Specified"),
    )
    ...
```

The problem is, if the value of `islandGroup` is something like 'Española' (i.e latin characters) I get a  status 500 error and the following Django error:

```
OperationalError: (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")


<WSGIRequest
path:/datazone/collections/find_island/,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'island_group': [u'Espa\ufffd']}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'__utma': '173650102.812455619.1337018914.1337629222.1337641044.38',
 '__utmb': '173650102.4.10.1337641044',
 '__utmc': '173650102',
 '__utmz': '173650102.1337613083.36.2.utmcsr=darwinfoundation.org|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/datazone/galapagos-research/search/',
 'csrftoken': '7cac07481c8ff5762fac33bf0b3590da',
 'sessionid': '4becce44a950091a3cf7d306633427b4'},
META:{'CSRF_COOKIE': '7cac07481c8ff5762fac33bf0b3590da',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/home/darwinfo/public_html',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=c297f86b353937f52abc36af8b4d595a; csrftoken=7cac07481c8ff5762fac33bf0b3590da; sessionid=4becce44a950091a3cf7d306633427b4; __utma=173650102.812455619.1337018914.1337629222.1337641044.38; __utmb=173650102.4.10.1337641044; __utmc=173650102; __utmz=173650102.1337613083.36.2.utmcsr=darwinfoundation.org|utmccn=
     ...
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19',
 'PATH': '/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/collections/find_island/',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/darwinfo/public_html/collections/find_island/',
 'QUERY_STRING': 'island_group=Espa%F1ola',
 'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING': 'island_group=Espa%F1ola',
 'REDIRECT_STATUS': '200',
 'REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID': 'T7rLMjIWL2YAAGS3N@sAAAET',
 'REDIRECT_URL': '/datazone/collections/find_island/',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '157.100.37.112',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '35245',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/datazone/collections/find_island/?island_group=Espa%F1ola',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/home/darwinfo/public_html/datazone/django.fcgi',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'/datazone',
 'SERVER_ADDR': '50.22.47.102',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',,
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache',
 'UNIQUE_ID': 'T7rLMjIWL2YAAGS3N@sAAAET',
 'wsgi.errors': <flup.server.fcgi_base.OutputStream object at 0x1707ab90>,
 'wsgi.input': <flup.server.fcgi_base.InputStream object at 0x16f2fad0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using mysql?  Looks like this was answered here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073295/django-character-set-with-mysql-weirdness

Comment: This is *definitely* a MySQL error. It has nothing to do with AJAX, JavaScript, or even Django (at least not directly).

Answer (score 0):

Check the collation type of each table, and make sure that they have the same collation.

After that check also the collation type of each table field that you have use in operation.

I had encountered the same error, and that tricks works .