# django-models database collations problems: declare a field that supports unicode?

Tags: django, django-models, collation, django-database

I encountered this problem. When I cannot assign a unicode string to `models.CharField` .

```
DatabaseError: (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073295/django-character-set-with-mysql-weirdness), but it doesn't seem to work for me. The database returns this error:

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './test_database/#sql-272e_1ba' to './test_database/[MY_TABLE_NAME]' (errno: 150)
```

Moreover, all these solutions appear to only work after the table is created, or modify the python manage.py sql APP_NAME output and manually create the tables.

Is there a way to fix this from when originally declaring the django models in the python code, so manage.py syncdb will just produce the right tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with your database configuration, not with Django.  My guess is that whatever DB you're using, it's configured to use latin1_swidish_ci for new tables.  You can [hook syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data) and alter the table there, but I think your better off fixing your DB config directly.