# Django Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)

Tags: django, utf-8

I am using Django 1.5.4 with Django-Regsitration module. whenever I try to register a user with Persian fonts I get this error:

```
DatabaseError at /accounts/register/
(1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: DatabaseError
```

I have the similar problem with other forms that I've created: Whenver I fill a field with Persian font, I get error like:

```
Warning at /accounts/profile/
Incorrect string value: '\xDA\xA9\xD8\xA7\xD8\xB1...' for column 'occupation' at row 1
```

To resolve it I did:

Using PhpMyAdmin I've changed collation of the database to 'utf8_general_ci

Had no effect.

I have also enforce the utf8 on the DB:

```
mysql> ALTER DATABASE djangodb  charset=utf8;
```

Still no effect.

So appreciate your hints.

Comment: You need to convert tables also: `ALTER TABLE yourtable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073295/django-character-set-with-mysql-weirdness

Comment: Indeed I needed to convert all the tables. This script did the job: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2150335/727695. Feel free to elaborate on the answer and I'll accept it. merci

Comment: Firstly you need to stop using the 1.X branch of Django.